# Buscar registro dentro de un array en mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Estoy tratando de crear un filtro sobre el siguiente esquema de datos.

```
[
    {
        "inventorydata": [
            [
                {
                    "ubicación": "principal",
                    "codigo": "123",
                    "descripcion": "prueba 1"
                },
                {
                    "ubicación": "secundaria",
                    "codigo": "456",
                    "descripcion": "prueba 2"
                },
                {
                    "ubicación": "tercera",
                    "codigo": "789",
                    "descripcion": "prueba 3"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "_id": "5fff69999119ae1a049955d3",
        "codigo_inventario": "ed9825f7-647b-443d-8e4c-69acf30cb292",
        "createdAt": "2021-01-13T21:43:53.318Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Necesito crear un filtro en mongoose que me permita ingresar a *inventorydata* y regresar el elemento correspondiente a un código en especifico.

```
app.post('/obtener', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const item = await imgModel.find({ 'inventorydata' : { $elemMatch: { 'codigo' : '1' } } });
    res.json(item)
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({ error_code: 1, err_desc: "Corupted excel file" });
  }

});
```

Estaba tratando de usar este código para filtrar y regresar el elemento pero obtengo una respuesta vacía []

Comment: Intenta eliminando el `$elemMatch` y usa solo `"inventorydata.codigo":"1"`

Comment: La respuesta es un [] sin datos

Comment: Solo quieres obtener ese unico elemento?. Para eso necesitas aggregate

Comment: Me pregunto si el esquema tiene la estructura correcta, pues `inventorydata` contiene un array de arrays `[[object1, object2, object3]]`, cuando puede ser estructurado como un array de objects `[object1, object2, object3]`, ¿Puedes confirmar? Lo comento porque así como lo muestras, se tendría que transversar 2 arrays para llegar al dato `codigo`.

Comment: Tienes razón, es un array de arrays y es un problema al momento de guardar los datos, voy a tratar de solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de la base que el array anidado es el problema, puedes utilizar la sigueinte query usando `aggregate`:

- Primero coger la primera posición del array para cada valor `inventorydata`.
- Después utilizar `$filter` en `$project` para filtrar el valor que quieres en el array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "inventorydata": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$inventorydata",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$inventorydata",
          "as": "i",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$i.codigo",
              "123"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n4HuzkWljiq)

Alternativamente, si solucionas el problema con el array anidado puedes utilizar `$elemMatch` como en [este ejemplo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WB-3fdTInnm). Pero **ten en cuenta** que `$elemMatch` te devuelve únicamente el primer objeto que coincide. En [este ejemplo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MRD5JVhSmpt) con dos objetos con el mismo código sólo devuelve uno.

En caso que haya más de un elemento en el array que quieras devolver puedes utilizar una query `aggregate` como en el primer ejemplo pero sin el paso de `$set` para quitar el array anidado. Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SN954cCrfyt)